# Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment

Tags: meteor

I am calling AWS service in Meteor to get `imageId`. After successfully get `imageId` I want to insert it in `Mongo.Collection`, but my insert code is not working and it gives following error:

> Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.

Here is my code:

```js
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
var params = {
  DryRun: false,
  Owners: [
    '12345678'
  ]
};
ec2.describeImages(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) { 
    console.log(err); // an error occurred
  } else {  
    var strData= JSON.stringify(data)

    var Images =  strData.Images
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(strData);

    var arrImages = jsonData.Images;

    var _ImageId=arrImages[0].ImageId;
    console.log("AMI IMAGE  is "+_ImageId)

    CreateInstense.insert({
      AMIIMAGE:_ImageId,
      InstenceId:"instanceId"
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do exactly what your error says: wrap your callback with [`Meteor.bindEnvironment`](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#bind-environment).

```js
ec2.describeImages(params, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (err, data) {
  // ...
}));
```

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted you, this is clearly the correct answer. I upvoted.